# Why is polyacetylene an insulator?

Tags: organic-chemistry, energy, molecular-orbital-theory, metal

Recently I have studied Huckel-theory and I appreciated how this approach is suitable to provide simple models to understand chemical behaviour.

However, it is highly approximate and qualitative at best.

According to Huckel's theory, for example, the homo-lumo gap decreases going on to add carbon atoms to the chain. And so, I could wrongly suppose that polyacetylene is a metal (the band gap shall be very small).

Why is not so? Which is the 'approximate' assumption in this theory that predicts an incorrect result?

Comment: Polyacetylene can be conducting (check here : https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/chemistry/laureates/2000/macdiarmid-lecture.pdf). I think what you are trying to ask is why doesn't the bandgap become zero? Why does the bandgap settle into a constant value?

Comment: In the solid, while the polymer chain can be very long the conjugation is not due to twists & turns and interactions with other chains. Conjugation may only be a few $10$'s of carbons long . Furthermore odd number of C atoms leads to two possible conjugations with a non-bonding electron (also called 'topological kink' or soliton) between them. This can diffuse up and down the conjugation. When doped polyacetylene can conduct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peierls_transition I *think* that the part that Huckel theory misses, is the electron-electron repulsions. Localisation of electrons due to repulsion is what drives the Peierls distortion. (Disclaimer: I don't know much about this, though.)

Comment: The single e in each carbon p orbital to a chemist naturally forms alternating double and single bonds, physicists call this 'dimerisation' and 'symmetry breaking' and leads to Peierls distortion. i.e alternate double & single bonds. As above, odd numbers of  C atoms leads to a 'radical' or 'non-bonding' electron at the interface of single /double conjugation, a soliton.

Comment: Porphyrin's comments will explain most of what you need with this addendum: due to the Peierl 's distortion, the band gap is greater than zero due the the polymer chain not being a rigid, conjugated rod along the whole length (due to entropy, but I'm not a free energy expert). This means there is a band gap, leading to semi conductor properties. This is overcome by doping, to give rise to a polymeric conductor.

Comment: its due the peierls disortion. According to the huckels theory, the polyacetylene should be behaving like metal. but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

When constructing the Hamiltonian for a Hückel system, we assume maximal orbital overlap for neighboring atoms, and zero overlap for all the others. This implies that the bonding at any bond and atom is perfectly symmetric, which would then lead to a conductor at infinite chain lengths.

In reality, this highly symmetric structure is obviously not the preferred one: the PAc forms isolated double and single bonds.
This formation of asymmetric sections on the molecule can be conceptually explained by Peierls distortion, as already mentioned by kiran, porphyrin and orthocresol.

So I guess the reason why Hückel theory fails at this molecule is its assumption of perfect symmetry. Simple Hückel thoery can never account for more complicated orbital overlap, bond length differences, twisted double bonds etc. etc.

Comment: I really think to answer this fully you have to at least mention Peierl's theorem and the associated distortion (see e.g. https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/752.mf1i.spring03/PeierlsTrans.htm ) and that for a half filled band, as in polyacetylene, the observed long-short ordering of the bonds is what is predicted.